# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site_domain_v2339b81_uniq" already exists

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error when I try to migrate. I tried to solve a `Site does not exist` error by doing this:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake sites zero
python manage.py showmigrations
sites
 [ ] 0001_initial
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

However this did not fix the problem. Any idea how I can fix this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation
>   "django_site_domain_v2339b81_uniq" already exists

**EDIT**

Here is what `showmigrations` shows:

```
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_domain_unique
```

I believe this may be the error

Comment: Why are you faking migrations? What's the original error that you tried to solve by doing this/

Comment: Yeah it was a mistake. The original error was `Site does not exist`. I believe my `SITE_ID` was wrong. However I have updated my code in my edit if you'd like to check it out.

Comment: I still don't get your original issue and why it is related to Migrations. Site does not exist simply means there is *missing data*. You might just have to add your site name to the Site table.

Comment: The site is already in the table, with it's name and domain. I've checked in my shell with `for i in Site.objects.all(): print(i, i.domain, i.name, i.id)` `>>> mysite.com mysite.com mysite.com 2` - `SITE_ID = 2` in settings aswell.

Comment: What is in your `0002_alter_domain_unique` migration file?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that this has already run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your DB is already migrated till the migration 0002.

Run `python manage.py migrate --fake sites 0002` - see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes that works, thankyou! Could you explain what you mean by `Looks like your DB is already migrated till the migration 0002` ?

Comment: Oh so your migration 0002 was trying to add a unique constraint of some kind. This is clear from the mysql error `django_site_domain_v2339b81_uniq` already exists. This tells me that the unique constraint already exists, which implies this migration has already run.

Comment: Caveat : if this migration file is doing more than one thing, perhaps also creating a model A, and for whatever reason failed in between before creating the model, then your faking of the same will lead to more errors. Let's say after the unique constraint, you created table A, but the migration failed between the two steps. Now that you've faked it, django assumes table A was also created, whereas in reality it hasn't.

Comment: So in future if I fake only the unchecked boxes in `showmigrations`, I shouldn't have any problem with that?

Comment: unchecked box means the migration is yet to run. It's not a big in itself. You&#39;ve somehow reached an inconsistent state, perhaps by regenerating migrations or replacing the db from elsewhere.

Comment: Ah right. May have been from inconsistent states between my development and production environment.